# Matrix vectorization using SIMD

Tags: c++, gcc, vectorization, compiler-optimization, simd

I'm trying to vectorized the following loop (only the inner) :

```
for (int i =0; i<n; i++){
    const int line = i * width;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        a[line + j] = 3;
    }
}
```

but I'm getting the following error:

not vectorized: not suitable for gather D.38226_277 = *D.38225_276;

I googled around and it's seems the compiler does not vectorize because, he does not know the data is contiguous.
I'm sure the data ([line + j]) is contiguous.
How can i tell to the compiler to trust me and vectorize the loop ?

I'm using GCC 4.7

---

**Edit**:

I was able to vetorize the loop without any change in the code using Intel Compiler.

Comment: This article provides a ton of tips for `Auto-vectorization with gcc 4.7` http://locklessinc.com/articles/vectorize/ you do not mention which version of `gcc` you are using but it should be helpful

Comment: for (int i =0;i<n<i++) you should make the second < to a ;.

Comment: Can you provide a small example that compiles and produces the problem? Also, please provide the arguments you are passing to `gcc` as well.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, thanks for the link, it is very useful! I Will read and try some tips from the link, and after i will post the results

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro Any results from this?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, sorry for not post the feedback, i read your link and as very helpful. But i started using intel compile instead gcc. He was capable to vetorize the loop without any changes. It´s seems Intel Compiler is more mature for SIMD optimization.

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro Makes complete sense, thanks for the update and I am not surprised that the Intel compiler makes better use of SIMD optimization.